# how do i access a image files on my local system to get its bitmap and assign it to a imageview in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

The path is of my local system looks like E:\Images\pic1.jpg

```
File file = new File(path);                                                                  
Log.d("swati","load bitmap from source "+file.getPath()+"  " +file.exists());                
  if (file.exists()) {                                                                       
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());                                       
 }
```

the `file.exists` returns `false` thus causing null pointer exception ... please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I let users access the internal storage directory of my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579869/how-can-i-let-users-access-the-internal-storage-directory-of-my-app)

Comment: in the given link it solves problem for the data in the SDcard or in the device respective to the app .. but in my case i want to access data from local system i.e. laptop and not from device. the file.exists() itself returns false. so cant move forward to make stream or anything.

Comment: so u r using ur android on your laptop?

Comment: i am trying with the emulator

Comment: but your emulator is also an android device, have u tried working with the code given in other question? i think that shouls work as sooner or later u will test on android device for sure

Comment: If you want to access the image from the PC/laptop you need to write a server(could be in java) for that. You have to send a request to the server(PC) and it will send the respose to the client (emulator).