# How to save a file that is accessible to the user outside of the app and also deletes on app uninstall?

Tags: android

Requirements of app:

- Saved files visible in stock device's file browser. (for user manipulation)
- Files are deleted when app is uninstalled.

I came across this post ([How can I let users access the internal storage directory of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579869/how-can-i-let-users-access-the-internal-storage-directory-of-my-app)) where the OP seemed to be wanting the same behavior I do and seemed to have it solved by using getExternalFilesDir() [last post] but when I use that method my files are not visible to the user outside of my app. So how do I get both functionalities in my app?

```
externalDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);
File myDir = new File(externalDir.toString() + "/my_snapshots");
myDir.mkdirs()
String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> seemed to have it solved by using getExternalFilesDir()

That is the correct solution.

> when I use that method my files are not visible to the user outside of my app

That is because you did not index the files using `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method. Once you do that, MTP clients and any on-device apps that use `MediaStore` will see your files.

Comment: Aw crap I forgot to say that I have used scanFile(). And I know scanFile() works because if I save the file to internal public the image shows up in the gallery.

Comment: Added the pertinent psuedo-code to see if you can spot something that may be off.

Comment: @shoota: I have had no problems with `scanFile()` in conjunction with `getExternalFilesDir()`, though it may require you to do a "refresh" on the client side, or unplug/re-plug-in the device, to get it to pick up the change. The main difference in my code versus yours is that I use `getAbsolutePath()` instead of `toString()`, though in this case I'm not sure that there's a difference. The files will show up in `Android/data/your.application.id.here/files/` on external storage (which, due to Googly stupidity, is typically called "Internal Storage" in a desktop file browser).

Comment: I can see my file using AFT under `Android/data/com.my_company/my_snapshots` so we know it's there but why is it not showing under Samsung's My Files app?

Comment: @shoota: Since I have no idea what Samsung's My Files app looks at, I can't answer that. Bear in mind that many devices don't have a "stock device's file browser", and that such apps' behavior can vary widely.